# Multiple sort on Array for UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios7, parse-platform

I have an array of categories returned from a parse.com query (sorted ascending) that are listed in a TableView.

I want to place a category called "Everything" at the top of the list and then sort the rest of the list ASC. I'm thinking I should use NSDescriptor, NSComparator or NSPredicate but wanted to get some feedback on the best route.

Another angle I thought might work is to extract "Everything" out of the array and put it in a string and then use 2 custom cells and put "Everything" on top.

Any advice on which option would be best? Or is there another route I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by copying the results Array into a mutable Array and then sorted the Array.

```
NSMutableArray *sort = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.objects];
id tmp=[sort objectAtIndex:6];
[sort removeObjectAtIndex:6];
[sort insertObject:tmp atIndex:0];
```